# Keep value after closing dialog fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I create dialog box by extending `AppCompatDialogFragment()`. I have one `EditText` field and Positive/Negative `button`. When I click on the Positive `button` I want to keep the value on the `EditText`, so when I reopen the dialog the value will be already written there.

Positive button (inside `onCreateDialog()`) - I send text to `MainActivity`

```
.setPositiveButton("apply", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            (activity as MainActivity?)?.updateDelay(textDelay.text.toString())
        })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store edit text data from an Android dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761497/how-to-store-edit-text-data-from-an-android-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface which passes the value back if the dialog is closed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27761620/9077356

If you want to permanently store the value and use it all around your project, you can also store it in `Sharedpreferences`.

Here`s an very simple tutorial of how to use `SharedPreferences`:
https://dev.to/victordgrandis/how-to-store-data-in-sharedpreferences-3a36

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save this value while app is open
use static value like in JAVA

```
public static String objectName = "";
```

and in Kotlin

```
companion object {

var objectName : String= ""
}
```